# Prove that a given recursion sequence converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm given:

$$\begin{align*}
x_1&=\frac32\\\\
x_{n+1}&=\frac3{4-x_n}
\end{align*}$$

How do I go about to formally prove the sequence converges and show it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ decreasing? Is $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ bounded below?

Comment: What I wrote is all I am given.

Comment: Let me rephrase: prove that $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is both decreasing and bounded below. Do you know how proving this helps you?

Comment: If it's bounded below, I can assume the sequence converges right ?


And showing it's decreasing will let me find the limit ?

Comment: No, for instance $(\sin(n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$is bounded below and it doesn't converge. You need something more to be sure it converges.

Comment: Do you mean I need more info given or I need to think more ?

Do I need to show it has an infimum ?

Comment: In order to establish convergence, in addition to the fact that the sequence is decreasing, you need to prove that is bounded below.

Comment: Yes I saw the edit.

Showing it's decreasing should be done by induction, I'm not really sure to apply it to this recursive sequence.

Comment: To prove that $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges it suffices to show that $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded below and decreasing.

You prove it is decreasing using induction. The base case $n=1$ is a simple calculation. For the induction step, assume $x_{n+1}<x_n$. The goal is to prove that $x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}$. The following equilavences hold: $$\begin{align} x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}&\iff \dfrac{3}{4-x_{n+1}}<\dfrac{3}{4-x_n}\\
&\iff 4-x_n < 4-x_{n+1}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(why?)}\\
&\iff x_{n+1}<x_n\end{align}$$
and $x_{n+2}<x_{n+1}$ follows by modus ponens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We prove by induction that:

1. $1<x_n<3$
2. $x_n$ is decreasing.

The base case is obvious. Now assume that $1<x_{n-1}<3$ for some $n$. Then
$$
\frac{3}{4-1}< \frac{3}{4-x_{n-1}}<\frac{3}{4-3}
$$
or, after simplifying, $1<x_n<3$, so $1.$ holds for $n$. Also, note that $1<x_{n-1}<3$ implies
$$
(x_{n-1}-1)(x_{n-1}-3)<0\Rightarrow 3<4x_{n-1}-x_{n-1}^2
$$
so
$$
x_n=\frac{3}{4-x_{n-1}}<x_{n-1}
$$
So $2.$ holds as well. Now by the monotone convergence theorem, $x_n$ converges. With a little more work, we can show that this limit is actually $1$.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that it's bounded below by one and decreasing in order to prove the limit is 1 ?

Comment: @GinKin No. It's also bounded below by $0$ or $1/2$; you have to prove that $1$ is the infimum.

Comment: Maybe not completely rigorous, but since the sequence converges, for sufficiently large $n$ we get $a_{n+1}=a_{n}$. Thus if the desired limit is $L$, solving $L=\frac{3}{4-L}$ yields $L=1$.

Comment: Thanks you two. I went throught all of my notes and searched online and still can't really figure out how to prove 1 is the infimum for this question in a rigorus way.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $(x_{n})$ is monotonically decreasing.

The base case clearly holds.

Now assume true for $n=k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z_{+}}$.

So $x_{k+1}<x_{k}$

We can rearrange the terms in terms of its predecessors. Then we get

$$x_{k+1}=4-\frac{3}{x_{k+2}} \text{ , } x_{k}=4-\frac{3}{x_{k+1}} $$

Rearranging gives the desired result.

Claim: $x_{n}$ is bounded below.

Suppose not. Then for all $n^*$ larger than some $N \in \mathbb{Z_{+}}$,

$x_{n^*}<-4$  $\space$ (since $x_{n}$ is decreasing)

Now, this implies $4-x_{n^*}>8$ but then $x_{n^*+1}>1$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem that says for any recursion $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, convergence is guaranteed whenever $| g'(x) |< 1$.

In our case, $g(x) = \frac{3}{4-x}$.  This is clear since $x_{n+1} = g(x_n) = \frac{3}{4-x_n}$.

So lets evaluate the expression...

$g'(x) = \frac{3}{(4-x)^2}$, and we require $|g'(x)|<1$.  Obviously $g'(x)$ is always positive.

We have $\frac{3}{(4-x)^2}<1$, which simplifies to $3 < (4-x)^2 = 16 - 8x + x^2$

If you solve the quadratic inequality you will see that $x>4+\sqrt{3}$ or $x<4-\sqrt{3}$.

The latter case, $x<4-\sqrt{3}\approx 2.26795\ldots$, is the case we are in. Since $x_1 = \frac32 = 1.5$, we are in the appropriate range for convergence.

If your initial term $x_1$ is not in the appropriate range, convergence can still happen. It's just not guaranteed and deeper analysis is required.

Also, just because $x_1$ isnt in the proper intervals doesnt necessarily mean that some other $x_i$ down the line wont be, and when/if that is the case, convergence is once again guaranteed.  Once youre in the interval of convergence you stay there.